# Mock TypeScript class with private constructor using Jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

So, I'm a newbie in the TypeScript and Jest world. I've omitted part of my code samples for the sake of simplicity.

Basically, I have a `User` entity that has a private constructor because I'm using a static factory method in this class. This factory method returns a `User` instance when success or a list of `UserCreationFailure`s when some provided field is invalid.

My `User` entity looks like this (please, note that it is just a simplified pseudo-code):

```
export class User {
    // fields

    private constructor(name: string, email: string, password: string) {
      this.name = name;
      this.email = email;
      this.password = password;
    }
  
    public static create(name: string, email: string, password: string) : UserCreationFailure[], User {
        // validations
  
        return failures.length ? failures : new User(name, email, password;
    }
}
```

Also, I'm writing a test to ensures that my factory method works fine. My test looks like this:

```
it('should create user when all provided fields are valid', () => {
    // arrange
    // mock User class calling the private constructor
    const mockUser = MockUserClass('Bruno', 'bruno@geosapiens.com.br', '12345678');
    // act
    const result = User.create('Bruno', 'bruno@geosapiens.com.br', '12345678');
    // assert
    expect(result).toStrictEqual(mockUser);
});
```

But seems that I cannot use Jest to mock the `User` class who has a private constructor. I want this mocked user instance in the arrange phase of my test to compare it with the returned user instance by the factory method.

**So, my question is:** is there a way to use Jest to mock a TypeScript class with a private constructor, passing parameters to it?

I took a look at the Jest documentation about mocks, But I didn't find anything about this specific scenario.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've posted an answer that seems to solve your issue. If there is any problem with it, can you please share so I or someone else can work on it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Bernardo Duarte's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71160855/13332423) is already a solution, but I would like to add some additional information to it and propose also another way.

#### Other Solution

```ts
it('should create user when all provided fields are valid', () => {
    // arrange
    // NOTE: here you don't need to access the prototype & constructor
    // but you can directly use the class
    const mockUser = new (User as any)('Bruno', 'bruno@geosapiens.com.br', '12345678');
    // act
    const result = User.create('Bruno', 'bruno@geosapiens.com.br', '12345678');
    // assert
    expect(result).toStrictEqual(mockUser);
});
```

You can also use an helper function to call private constructors:

```ts
function privateFactory<T=any>(cls: any, ...args: any[]): T {
    return new cls(...args);
}
```

Then you can simply use it like this:

```ts
it('should create user when all provided fields are valid', () => {
    // arrange
    const mockUser = privateFactory<User>(User, 'Bruno', 'bruno@geosapiens.com.br', '12345678');
    // act
    const result = User.create('Bruno', 'bruno@geosapiens.com.br', '12345678');
    // assert
    expect(result).toStrictEqual(mockUser);
});
```

#### Explanation

Usually a class inherits callability from the `Function` prototype, so your `User` class implements the following interface:

```ts
{ new(name: string, email: string, password: string): User }
```

This means that you can call `new User('n', 'e', 'p')` because `User` supports the `new` operator for inheritance.

When you make a constructor private you are actually excluding the prototype callability from the class: for the TS compiler `User` does not have a definition for `new` operator.

Since TS is compiled to JS, the accessibility of a method is purely theoretical, it will not be compiled in any way. So you can force the compiler to interpret your `User` class as another type, the most common is `any` because is the more flexible:

```ts
/* TS */
new (User as any)('n', 'e', 'p');

/* JS */
new User('n', 'e', 'p')


// note you don't need to employ prototype at all
// as stated by Bernardo, but under the hood
// the JS interpret will do that anyway
/* TS */
new (User.prototype as any).constructor('n', 'e', 'p');

/* JS */
new User.prototype.constructor('n', 'e', 'p');
```

A further approach would include the use of [`ConstructorParameters<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#constructorparameterstype) to ensure the type check for the constructor parameters:

```ts
new (User as new(...args: ConstructorParameters<User>) => User)('n', 'e', 'p');
```

The problem is again that in order to use `ConstructorParameters` you need to have a public constructor. At last you can copy the signature of the private constructor in order to ensure the type checking:

```ts
new (User as any as new(name: string, email: string, password: string) => User)('n', 'e', 'p');

// To generalize/clean/reuse just define an helper type
type Constructor<T, Args extends any[]> = new(...args: Args) => T;
new (User as any as Constructor<User, [string, string, string]>)('n', 'e', 'p');
```

Lastly you can encapsulate the type assertion to any in a function argument:

```ts
function privateFactory<T=any>(cls: any, ...args: any[]): T {
    return new cls(...args);
}
```

Here when you pass anything as `cls` parameter, it will be automatically inferred as a `any` variable. You can call it as a constructor (`new cls(...args)`). The downside is that you can pass literally anything in that function (`privateFactory(undefined)` still compile) but it could break everything at runtime.

Answer (score 6):

There is a workaround the constructor method that doesn't even need `jest`.

All you have to do is to access the `User` `prototype`'s set the type as `any`, sou you're free to access it's private contents, then access `constructor` and call it. Since you're calling a constructor, don't forget to use the `new` keyword.

```js
it('should create user when all provided fields are valid', () => {
    // arrange
    const mockUser = new (User.prototype as any).constructor('Bruno', 'bruno@geosapiens.com.br', '12345678');
    // act
    const result = User.create('Bruno', 'bruno@geosapiens.com.br', '12345678');
    // assert
    expect(result).toStrictEqual(mockUser);
});
```

If you want to check if `mockUser` is indeed a `User` instance just use generics `expect(result).toStrictEqual<User>(mockUser);` and you'll find that it works like a charm.